# How to clean test DB after **all** test complete?

Tags: elixir, integration-testing, ex-unit

I have a module of tests that run synchronized one after the other.
I would like to clean all the changes done on the db by the tests after **all** tests complete, i.e. I want the data to persist in the db between one test to another.
My app is using a PostgreSQL database (`MyRepo`).
when I use `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.checkout(MyRepo)` in the `setup_all` function the DB gets cleaned after each test.
This is my `condig/test.exs` file:

```
config :my_repo, MyRepo,
       pool: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox,
       database: "my-repo-test",
       username: "postgres",
       password: "postgres",
       hostname: "localhost",
       port:     "5432",
       pool_size: 1,
       max_overflow: 0,
```

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: It's definitely an awful idea to store data in DB between tests. You have a lot of options to set data inside DB: setups, before callbacks, etc. This is how the unit tests should be done

Comment: this has nothing to do with unit testing

Answer (score 2):

You might use [`ExUnit.Callbacks.on_exit/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Callbacks.html#on_exit/2):

```
setup_all do
  on_exit fn -> Repo.cleanup() end
end
```